# No front speaker sound with after-market receiver using RCA

Tags: audio, audi, speakers

VEHICLE: 2008 A4 S-Line (Quattro)

FACTORY SOUND: Symphony II (Blaupunkt)

AFTER-MARKET RECEIVER: Pioneer AVH-X5700BHS

The Pioneer receiver I purchased has both a "pre-amp" side and RCA. For the last couple of years, I used an [ENFIG_SRWH_AUD3_HILO](https://enfigcarstereo.com/ENFIG_SRWH_AUD3_HILO.html) until the "pre-amp" side (for some unknown reason) worked intermittently then died. I took the unit out and tested that the RCA side still worked and so ordered [ENFIG_SRWH_AU2](https://enfigcarstereo.com/ENFIG_SRWH_AU2.html).

Oddly enough, all the rear (including sub) seems to work perfectly -- no low sound or anything. However, I have zero front speaker sound. I also attempted to switch the RCA cables just to see if I could route the rear sound to the front speakers, but there's nothing. My guess is that the front speakers need to be driven independently and I goofed.

Am I missing something obvious? Did I get the wrong cable? Is there no good way to use the RCA with the stock internals in this vehicle?

Thanks in advance.